# How do i join ContentDocumentLink with Account with SOQL query?

Tags: soql, inner-join

I want to find a file(ContentDocument) which is associated with a particular account with SOQL. I have tried below query.

```
Select LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where Account.Id == LinkedEntityId
```

But it throws me an error as `unknown error parsing query`

I understood both Object structure from [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm). 
Id of account is primary look like primary key of account entity and LinkedEntityId of ContentDocumentLink shows the reference type of field. It means it could be linked with other entity such as entityType, user and group(as permission is assigned).

So what is another possible way to find associated contentDocument from the account id or any suggestion on my existing query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **WHERE** clause has an issue.

It should be

`WHERE LinkedEntityId = :Account.Id`

Comment: I have changed query but the same error I got.

Comment: Where are you executing the query? In the developer console Query editor or in developer console execute anonymous window or in a class/trigger?

Comment: sanket. I am performing a query in the developer console query editor.

Comment: So in this case use following-
WHERE LinkedEntityId = '<AcountID>'
For example-
WHERE LinkedEntityId = '0017F000008xaWK'

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong with the syntax for using where clause:-

> As you are performing the query on ContentDocumentLink Object, so in
>   where Clause, for an expression, the left-hand side will having the
>   field name from Object on which you are performing the query.

Second thing, If you are referring a variable as an assigning value to a field in where clause inside SOQL query, You should use **=:** instead of **==**.

So in your case, It should be:-

```
 ContentDocumentLink  cdl= [ Select LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId =: Account.id];
```

> Note:- If you are doing this query in Developer console's query
>   editor, You need to give a hard-coded value of type account id. The
>   account id should be the id of the account on which you want to get
>   the associated documents details.

like this:-

```
Select LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId ='0015E00000V38u1QAB'
```

Comment: You may like to correct this -- *If you are referring a variable while comparing, You should use =: instead of ==* .. You still need `==` for comparison, it's just that if you are using bind variable, you need to use that using `value to compare == :myBindVariable`

Comment: Thanks, @JayantDas Can you explain more? It will be helpful.

Comment: As I mentioned, you need `==` for comparison. `=:` will just assign the value of the bind variable

Comment: I corrected my answer as follows:-  If you are referring a variable while comparing in where clause inside the SOQL query, You should use =: instead of ==.

Comment: Remember when you using `:=` in a WHERE clause (or any where you use =), that’s not comparison but assignment and that’s the difference that I want to highlight.

Comment: Thank a lot for correcting me. :)

Comment: Above solution works in the case we have LinkedEntityId. But what if we don't have LinkedEntityId.

Comment: LinkedEntityId is a mandatory field on ContentDocumentLink. If a record of type ContentDocumentLink exists, there must be LinkedEntityId. Anyways, what are you exactly looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to solve the above question.
I used a subquery concept for doing this.

```
 Select LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId,ShareType,Visibility from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN (Select Id From Case)
```

It solves my problem.